# Scrolling issues with mobile safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, mobile-safari

I've run into a weird error with the Safari browser on the iPad.

Here's my code:

CSS:

```css
#searchResults {
    border-style: none;
    background-color:#b00000;
    width:40%;    
    max-height:100%;    
    position:fixed;    
    left:40%;    
    overflow:hidden;    
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;    
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onClick = "buttonClick()"/>
<div id="searchResults">
    hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>hello<br>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function buttonClick() {
    document.getElementById('searchResults').style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

The popup div container is not able to be scrolled in mobile Safari, but if I eliminate the visiblity:hidden part then it scrolls just fine. I really can't eliminate the visibility:hidden part, but I'm not sure what to do.  I could dynamically create the div on the fly and then remove it when I'm done with it, but it seems that there should be an easier method.

​​[see Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXj9m/58/)

Comment: you could try using `display: none;` (hidden) and `display: block` (visible) instead.  Don't know if it would work but worth a shot I guess.

Comment: That works.  I'm not really sure why it works and the previous attempt didn't, but it did the trick.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so others can find help from it...

Comment: `position:fixed` doesn't work on many mobile browsers (behaving like `position:absolute` instead).  I don't have an iPad, so I don't know... does it work there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: none;` (hidden) and `display: block;` (visible) instead.

I don't know why that fixes it but it seems to do the trick.